# MySQL inserting ID into multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, insert

i got the following insert-command:

```
INSERT INTO PERSON ('Name','Age','Filename') VALUES ('Max',12,'Max_ID_.pdf');
```

i want to insert instead of 'Max_ID_.pdf' the string concartenated with the inserted id for this row. e.g.:

```
ID|Name|Age|Filename

2 |Max |12 |Max_2_.pdf
```

Comment: can you post more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert your row first, and than update it with the last inserted id:

```
INSERT INTO PERSON ('Name','Age','Filename') VALUES ('Max',12,'xxx');
UPDATE PERSON Filename=CONCAT(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'.pdf') where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

There is also a way to do it in one statement, maybe a little more complex, and maybe **will not work on every system**, e.g. if you use innodb or transactions:

```
INSERT INTO PERSON SET Filename = CONCAT((SELECT auto_increment FROM
information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='PERSON'), '.pdf'),
Name = 'Max', Age = '12'
```

Comment: Don't use the second method, especially not with innodb, or with transactions - it won't work.